# Fastest multithreaded radix sort

Tags: sorting

What is the fastest multithreaded radix sort code out there? I am using radix sort to sort the Morton/Hilbert keys when constructing a tree structure. The number of identical keys is in the range of 10-100. I also need the sorting code to return a permutation index array so that I can sort other elements according to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you can code on many core architectures such as GPUs, maybe this paper ["Fast 4-way parallel radix sorting on GPUs"](http://www.sci.utah.edu/~csilva/papers/cgf.pdf) can interest you.

Comment: I am looking for a CPU code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [p4est](http://www.p4est.org/)? It might have the kind of code you're looking for.